# How to create a product feature using query in cscart

Tags: php, cs-cart

I need to create a product feature via query. I created a product feature via admin panel, Its  working fine. But I need to create a product feature via query.

My query for create product feature :-

```
$data = array(
    array(
    'feature_code' => 'Make1',
    'company_id' => '0', 
    'feature_type' => 'M', 
    'categories_path' => '', 
    'parent_id' => '', 
    'display_on_product' => 'N', 
    'display_on_catalog' => 'N', 
    'display_on_header' => 'N', 
    'status' => 'A', 
    'position' => '0', 
    'comparison' => 'N')
);

db_query('INSERT INTO ?:product_features ?m', $data);    

$object_id = db_get_field('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'); 

$data = array(
    array(
    'feature_id' => $object_id,
    'description' => 'Make1', 
    'full_description' => 'Make1', 
    'prefix' => '', 
    'suffix' => '', 
    'lang_code' => 'en'
    )
);

db_query('INSERT INTO ?:product_features_descriptions ?m', $data);
```

But the fields are insert into table. But I not able to edit the product feature details in cscart. How Can I do. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$data = array(
    'feature_code' => 'Make1',
    'company_id' => '0', 
    'feature_type' => 'M', 
    'categories_path' => '', 
    'display_on_product' => 'N', 
    'display_on_catalog' => 'N'
);
$feature_id = db_query('INSERT INTO ?:product_features ?e', $data);    

$data = array(
    'feature_id' => $feature_id,
    'description' => 'Make1', 
    'full_description' => 'Make1', 
    'lang_code' => 'en'
);

db_query('INSERT INTO ?:product_features_descriptions ?e', $data);
```